# Python - How to convert this timestamp format to datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

I have the timestamp format such as "**2014-01-06T00:39:45.001+0000**" but I don't know exactly what this timestamp format is. So I can't convert it to datetime as I desired.

How can I convert it with Python?

Comment: @tback: or more specifically it is a profile of ISO 8601 described in [rfc 3339](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc3339) (+/- ":" in time offset)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`dateutil.parser.parse`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil):

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse("2014-01-06T00:39:45.001+0000")
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 6, 0, 39, 45, 1000, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can parse dates and times in arbitrary formats using [`datetime.strptime(date_string, format)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), with the grammar for defining `format` presented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

In this case:

```
 format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"
```

**Note:** `%z` is not supported before Python 3.2 for the `.strptime()` method.

Comment: It's in [the docs for 2.7.x](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: I guess I don't! You are right, but I can't see a reference to that behaviour in the docs; note (5) for `%z` doesn't mention it, although other notes mention the difference. I will edit my answer.